# Fetching TLD from ptr record?

Tags: perl, dns, reverse-dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extraction of TLD from urls and sorting domains and subdomains for each TLD file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031620/extraction-of-tld-from-urls-and-sorting-domains-and-subdomains-for-each-tld-file)

For example: fetching yahoo.com from the PTR record
45.36.190.206.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ir1.fp.vip.gq1.**yahoo.com**.

I am using Net::Nslookup; 
nslookup(host => "206.190.36.45", type => "PTR"); which returns ir1.fp.vip.gq1.yahoo.com.

Need to fetch just "yahoo.com" from the ptr record.

How to fetch this using perl ?

Comment: Is your question simply "How does one get the TLD of `ir1.fp.vip.gq1.yahoo.com`, namely `yahoo.com`?"

Comment: @ikegami yes need to fetch the TLD.

Comment: Regarding your deleted question, ::PortState merely checks if it can create the socket. For a connectionless protocol like UPD, that's a useless check because the remote machine is never contacted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your question simply "How does one get the TLD of `ir1.fp.vip.gq1.yahoo.com`, namely `yahoo.com`?"

```
use Domain::PublicSuffix qw( );

my $dps = Domain::PublicSuffix->new();

my $host = 'ir1.fp.vip.gq1.yahoo.com';

$host =~ s/\.\z//;  # D::PS doesn't handle "domain.com.".
my $root = $dps->get_root_domain($host)
   or die $dps->error();

say $root;
```

By the way, you can use the builtin / system call `gethostbyaddr` to get the PTR record.

```
use Socket qw( inet_aton AF_INET );
my $host = gethostbyaddr(inet_aton("206.190.36.45"), AF_INET);
```

Comment: In this case, the 'root' can resolve to the original IP address, but that's not always going to be the case.

Comment: yep i used a if block to handle that have a list of 500 odd IPs, did fail for a couple of them.